# Roll up of all of the items in the related list in the current WEEK only

Tags: apex, trigger, related-list

I created a roll up summary to get the sum of all of the quantity in my related list. I need to sum up all of the quantity of the items which date__c is within the current week. What approach can I use to achieve this? As much as possible I want to avoid triggers and much coding. Thanks in advance. 
Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain you can use relative dates in a Rollup Summary filter.  However, you could create a checkbox/formula field on the related record that evaluates if the date__c is greater than or equal to this week (today()-7 . . . or somethign along that line).  And then write the rollup filter to evaluated if the checkbox/formula is TRUE.